# Parse axios alert message into React DOM

Tags: reactjs, axios

I have message-send form in react with working backend on node server. When I send message I get alerts (which i take from the axios tutorial).
It looks loke this:

```
axios({
  /* here sending data */
}).then((response)=>{
    if (response.data.msg === 'success') {
        alert("Message sent successfully.");
    }
});
```

And now i want to show "Message sent successfully" on my react-app page in DOM as div under sending form or as popup on the page. How can this be done most easily?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `alert` you can use `setState` to put the message in your component state and use that in the render method.

**Example**

```js
function axios() {
  return new Promise(resolve =>
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve({ data: { msg: "success" } });
    }, 1000)
  );
}

class App extends React.Component {
  state = { message: "Loading..." };

  componentDidMount() {
    axios({
      /* sending data goes here */
    }).then(response => {
      if (response.data.msg === "success") {
        this.setState({ message: "Message sent successfully." });
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    return <div> {this.state.message} </div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```